# Vue.js passing functions to props not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem that passing functions to components is not working the way it's specified in the documentation.

This is in my app.js

```
methods: {
    updateAnswer: function(question) {
        console.log('question: '+question);
    }
}
```

This is in my html-file:

```
<multiplechoice class="question counterIncrement counterShow active" id="q2" whenanswered="{{ updateAnswer('1') }}"></multiplechoice>
```

This is in my components.js file:

```
props: [
    'whenanswered'
],

ready: function() {
    this.whenanswered();
},
```

I have already tried this:

```
props: [
    { name: 'whenanswered', type: Function}
];
```

but still no luck.

This is in my console when I load the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.whenanswered is not a function
```

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<multiplechoice class="question counterIncrement counterShow active" id="q2" :whenanswered="updateAnswer('1')"></multiplechoice>
```

Without the ':'(same as v-bind) like you did will only send a string and not evaluate. Even with those `{{ }}`.

But remember that your `updateAnswer`function should return a function. Since your prop will execute `updateAnswer('1')` and your `multiplechoice`actually expects a function that will be executed when it wants.

```
methods: {
  whenanswered: function(question) { // or whenanswered (question) { for ES6 
    return function () { ... } // or () => {...} for ES6
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A fiddle would help, but basically, you need:

```
methods: {
    whenanswered: function(question) {
        ...
    }
}
```

if you wanna call that function. A prop is just a string, not a function.

Example:

```
<div id="app">
    Loading...
    <data-table on-load="{{onChildLoaded}}"></data-table>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
    methods: {
        onChildLoaded: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    },
    components: {
        'data-table': {
            template: 'Loaded',    
            props: ['onLoad'],
            ready: function () {
                this.onLoad('the child has now finished loading!')
            }
        }
    }
});
```